# How to export or download all data from Adobe Lightroom on web?

Tags: lightroom, web, export

I have been using the Adobe Lightroom in the web for the past month, where I have created more than 30 collections with over than 2000 images.

Now I want to store everything on my new external drive but the only way I know to download the images is: clicking a specific image and download the image from there (using the download button).

**How can I export all that data/download all the data, from the Adobe Lightroom in the web?**

Comment: Nevermind, **problem** was **solved** with the new updates.  

By accessing the collections through the shared link (either on FB Messenger or other platform) a button "Download" is going to appear and let you download all the collection through a .zip file.

Comment: vtc b/c Problem resolved itself. Since question is about a web app, it is unlikely to be relevant in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved, per [Goncalo Peres](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/89057/#comment161006_89057) (Jun 22 '17 at 17:35):

> Nevermind, problem was solved with the new updates. By accessing the collections through the shared link (either on FB Messenger or other platform) a button "Download" is going to appear and let you download all the collection through a .zip file.